ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Route Not Found (404) on All Routes in Development Environment
I'm having trouble with an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project that works fine locally, but when I try to run it on a virtual machine (VM), a specific route always returns a 404 error. Here's what I've tried and the details:
Project Details:
Framework: .NET 8.0
Environment: Development
Issue: The /User/LoginUser route returns a 404 error on the VM, but works locally.
Logs:
Local Machine:
The route /User/LoginUser is matched correctly, and the Razor Page renders as expected.
Virtual Machine:
The route /User/LoginUser returns a 404 error. Debug logs show that no endpoint matches the route.
launchSettings.json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "User/LoginUser",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5212",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();


builder.Services.AddSingleton<EmailService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOperacaoService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<AndamentoController>();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/User/LoginUser"; 
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/AccessDenied"; 
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("OperacaoPolicy", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new OperacaoRequirement()));
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, OperacaoAuthorizationHandler>();

var app = builder.Build();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
    StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(app.Environment, app.Configuration);
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Local Machine:
The route /User/LoginUser is matched correctly, and the Razor Page renders without issues.
Virtual Machine:
The route /User/LoginUser results in a 404 error. Debug logs indicate that no endpoints match the requested route.
Question:
What could be causing the route to return a 404 error on the VM but work fine on my local machine? Is there something specific in the environment or configuration that could be causing this issue?


Try to install url rewrite module first and check it again. Scroll to the bottom and find the download links.



Navigate to publish folder and  find the project_name.exe, double-click it then it will start with kestrel webserver, then check the 404 error exist or not,


i tried to execute my project_name.exe in published folder, but the error keeps happening,unfortunally i could not install  url rewrite i do not have permision on vm

Hello Lucas, could you kindly create a brand new sample project which can reproduce the issue and share with us. Then we can check the issue is related to the project or the environment.

I was facing similiar problem.
Check your target pages in project’s csproj file. I solved this problem by removing the below code from the csproj file:
<ItemGroup>
<_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Areas\Admin\Pages\Application\MarketLinks.cshtml" />
<_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Areas\Admin\Pages\User\Edit.cshtml" />
<_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Areas\Member\Pages\Myapp\AnounceList.cshtml" />
<_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Areas\Member\Pages\Myapp\AppDatas.cshtml" />

I write detail information in my article about this problem :
https://emrekabali.medium.com/razor-pages-asp-page-not-working-7b44e6a67bf2

This is a copy of your own code, it's better to explain how to solve the problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
